# Will gobject.idle_add(function) block until executing the function is finished?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gobject

I am writing a python software using gtk in combination with threads. Now there is a part where I have to use something like `gobject.idle_add(function)`.

My problem is, that the part after that call should really be executed after the function i passed to idle_add is finished.

```
do_some_things_before()
gobject.idle_add(do_something)
do_some_things_after()
```

My question is: Will `gobject.idle_add(do_something)` block until `do_something()` is finished executing?

Thanks,
patsimm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `idle_add()` merely queues your function to be run the next time no events are pending. You will need to add some synchronization code.

Furthermore, if the callback function returns the GLib constant `TRUE` (not sure what the PyGTK+ equivalent is) the function will be requeued for the next idle point, so there's no point in waiting for a function that could potentially never really be finished. (Return `FALSE` to remove the function from the queue.)

I don't see a reference to the C equivalent `gdk_threads_idle_add()` in the PyGTK+ reference; I'm going to assume the one you're calling will also run the function on the GUI thread.

Comment: To complete the understanding of how the GLib main even loop works I always suggest read the documentation, it's really useful, [here the link](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description)